# Fire a native DLL (from the entry point) in CAB install (on Windows Mobile)

Tags: windows-ce, cab

Knowing the entry point in **native Windows CE DLL** and providing it with CAB file is it possible to run the function at some point of installation? Is it possible to put such 'wish' to **_setup.xml** or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done, though it's not as straightforward as you're probbly wishing.

You can create a [custom setup DLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa924308.aspx) and include that in your installer.  The installer will call entry points (e.g. `Install_Exit`) in that DLL during install.  You could then put a `LoadLibrary` \ `GetProcAddress` \ method call into that method.